# Objective-C Method Call in Category Question

Tags: objective-c

I have extended one of my classes with a category to deal with parsing a specific XML file.
In the class `ListBuilder.m` I have defined method named `newsloop`, which simply cycles through a list of items once the list has been built.

`-(void)newsloop;` is declared in a private category declared inside `ListBuilder.m`.

In my category, `ListBuilder+XMLParser.m`, is where I call newsloop once the list has been built:

```
-(void) parserDidEndDocument: (NSXMLParser *)parser {
    if ( [self.newslist count] >= 2 )
        [self newsloop];    // warning flagged here
    else
        // to some other default stuff
}
```

Xcode (4, if it matters) shows a warning `Method '-newsloop' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`.

Why would cause a warning, since, if I'm right, categories have access to all the methods defined in the class they are extending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler still needs to know that the `newsloop` method (or selector) exists. When it's compiling your category file this method has not been declared anywhere so it will generate a warning.

If you want to keep this method private, you should create a ListBuilder+Private.h file where you declare any shared private methods, and include this in both ListBuilder.m and your ListBuilder+XMLParser category.

Technically users of your code can include the header themselves and also call the method, but there are other ways to do that anyway since there is no such thing as private/public methods in Objective-C. Also, including a header with 'Private' in it and calling methods is their problem, not yours.

Answer (score 1):

The category doesn't know that the method `newsloop` exists in the class, because it's not declared in the header file; only in a private category. That's why you get the warning. You should declare the method in the header file or in a protocol that the class implements.

Comment: That part was not mentioned in the docs I've read.  Oversight maybe?

Comment: Not every situation is in the docs, but it's probably there that you use header files to communicate classes capabilities to users of those classes. Private categories are not in the header, and so no code outside the class implementation file knows about it.